# Solving a complex Gaussian integral using a rectangle

Tags: complex-analysis

Let C be the circumference of the rectangle with the vertices $-a, a, a +ib, -a+ib, a > 0$, traversed counterclockwise.  Show that the sum of the integrals of $e^{-z^2}$ along the upper and lower horizontal legs can be written as $$2 \int_0^a e^{-x^2}dx-2e^{b^2} \int_0^ae^{-x^2}cos2bxdx$$

and that the sum of the inregrals along the verticdal legs on the right and left can be written as $$ie^{-a^2} \int_0^be^{y^2-2iay}dy-ie^{-a^2} \int_0^be^{y^2+2iay}dy$$

Thus, with the aid of Cauchy's Theorem show that $$\int_0^ae^{-x^2}cos2bxdx = e^{-b^2}\int_0^ae^{-x^2}dx+e^{-(a^2+b^2)}\int_0^be^{y^2}sin2aydy$$

I drew the rectangle mentioned above and labeled the sides (starting at the bottom along the x axis) 1,2,3 and 4.  The first part here considers sides 1 and 3, specifically $\int_1 e^{-z^2} + \int_3 e^{-z^2}$.  I parameterized z to be x, as these are the horizontal vertices of the rectangle.  That gave me $\int_{-a}^a e^{-x^2} + \int_{a+ib}^{a-ib} e^{-x^2}$.  For the first section of this $\int_{-a}^a e^{-x^2} = \sqrt{\pi}*erf(a) = \sqrt{\pi}*\frac{2}{\sqrt{\pi}}\int_0^ae^{-x^2}dx$, which comes out to what I need.

The second chunk of the first part is giving me problems.  If I take the same approach, $\int_{a+ib}^{a-ib} e^{-x^2} = -\frac{\sqrt{\pi}}{2}(erf(a-ib)+erf(a+ib))$.  Following through on that approach does not give me $-2e^{b^2} \int_0^ae^{-x^2}cos2bxdx$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try writing the integral along side 3 in terms of a **real** variable: $z=x+ib$, so
$$\int_3 e^{-z^2}\,dz=-\int_{-a}^a e^{-x^2+b^2-2bxi}\,dx
  =-e^{b^2}\int_{-a}^ae^{-x^2}(\cos2bx-i\sin2bx)\,dx$$
and so on.

Comment: Wouldn't $(\cos2bx-i\sin2bx)$ have to equal $2\cos2bx$ for that to work?  I can follow what you have here (I never thought of using $z = x + ib$), but I don't see how to get the $2\cos2bx$.

Comment: I worked out sides 2 and 4 thanks to your suggestion, but I am still unable to finish out part 3 based on the above comment.

Comment: I see it now, the integral is from -a to a and the integral I am looking for is from 0 to a.

Comment: Apologies for lack of replies to your comments, I had to go away and do something.  But you seem to have everything sorted out now.